# how to Enable Disable multiple textboxes with checkboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to make my textboxes to be disable onload of the page and enable it when the coresponding checkbox is checked..the textbox wil only enable if the coresponding checkbox..how can i do this..below is my html code..i need a javascript to run the function i want..

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<form name="f1" action="showReceipt.php" method="POST">
<table >
<tr><td>Transaction ID <input type="text" name="txtID"> <?php echo date("m / d / Y");?></td></tr>
<tr><td><h2>Your Order:</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td><input  type="checkbox"  name="cbItem[]" value="Chicken Joy"> Chicken Joy (PhP 90.00)</td> <td>Quantity <input type="text" name="txtQty[Chicken Joy]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input  type="checkbox" name="cbItem[]" value="Jolly Spaghetti"> Jolly Spaghetti (PhP 50.00)</td> <td>Quantity <input type="text"  name="txtQty[Jolly Spaghetti]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbItem[]" value="Yum Burger"> Yum Burger (PhP 29.00)</td> <td>Quantity <input type="text" name="txtQty[Yum Burger]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbItem[]" value="Jolly Twirls"> Jolly Twirls (PhP 25.00)</td> <td>Quantity <input type="text" name="txtQty[Jolly Twirls]"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbItem[]" value="Big Champ"> Big Champ (PhP 120.00)</td> <td>Quantity <input type="text" name="txtQty[Big Champ]"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Amount Given: <input type="text" name="txtAmount"></td> <td><input type="submit" name="btnGen" value="Generate Receipt">  <input type="reset" value="Clear">


</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("myText").disabled = true try this...

Comment: what are u trying ??? plz post the your javascript code too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById("mybox");

  textbox.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");

  document.getElementById("checkMe").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var textbox = document.getElementById("mybox");
    textbox.removeAttribute("disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkMe" />
<input type="text" id="mybox" />
```

You can try execute each process with Events. When the page is finished loading all elements, set the attribute of the box to `disabled`. then listen for another event of clicking a checkbox. when that event fires, remove the checkbox's `disabled` state.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable your input from start, your input should look like this

```
<input type = "Text" name = "firstname" id="1" disabled="disabled" />
```

Or if you want to disable it with javascript, you have to execute it on load. Something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById('1').disabled = true;
};
```